# Where should I put shared testing utilities in a multi-module Maven project?

Tags: java, maven-2, osgi, package

I probably sholdn't obsess about this too much, but my project has a very structured layout that I have become very fond of. Having that much structure has actually proven to be useful, this time, so I don't really want it to become messy again.

To start with, each module consists of several Java packages:

```
com.mycompany.mysoftware.modulename
com.mycompany.mysoftware.modulename.impl
com.mycompany.mysoftware.modulename.osgi
com.mycompany.mysoftware.modulename.test
```

The main code lives in `.impl`. Interfaces, some enums and some data container classes that are used by other modules live in the package with no suffix. There's OSGi specific code (`BundleActivator`s etc.) in the `.osgi` package and unit tests in the `.test` package.

Now I have classes that fake a module to be used in testing others. I'm wondering whether I should put those in the `.test` package of a `common` module that already contains shared libraries for the main code, or whether I should have a new module `test` that I can set up a different dependency scope for in Maven.

**ETA**: One problem I'm having is that I get circular dependencies: if I have two modules and the unit tests in each require a fake of the other, the module containing the fake has a dependency on the module containing the interface, which is the same module that contains the unit test. So, the fake should be together with the test, but that leads to a lot of code duplication. Or, for each module I make a fake module, but that makes me feel it's getting out of hand...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't want your testing code to be packaged in the common module used by main code, do you?

So the answer seems obvious to me: create a test module and use it as dependency with a test scope.

(**EDIT:** I'm putting an answer to the problem mentioned in the update of the question below)

Regarding the circular dependencies, what about putting the interfaces in a separated module?

Comment: Well, it wouldn't be packaged if it's in the test subdirectory of that common module. Still, the dependency scope is probably the most important aspect, I guess.

Comment: That's true. But you couldn't depend on that code in several modules if it's in the test subdirectory of the common module.